# aplicar regex en fluent validation

Tags: c#, regex

Tengo  un campo de RFC, al que quiero validar en c#, con el fluent validator, el tema es que en TS se aplica correctamente, y en c# al parecer no coincide:

Este es mi regex:

```
Regex rxRFC = new Regex(@"^[A-Z&Ñ]{3,4}[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9A]*$");
```

Y aqui la regla que quiero aplicar con fluent validation

```
    RuleFor(x => x.data.Rfc).Matches(rxRFC).WithMessage("Campo 'rfc' formato invalido");
```

Me falta algún caracter en el regex?

Texto de ejemplo
ABCD9901011X1

Comment: Y en TS como lo tienes?

Comment: Con qué es lo que no coincide? Es imposible responder sin un texto de ejemplo

Comment: Listo añadí un texto de ejemplo

Comment: Buenas, lo he probado con tu ejemplo,  lo curioso es que a mí me funciona en c#
(4.7.2 net framework) y con el fluent Validation(11.0.0) por tanto, no creo que sea el **regex**, puede ser que este respecto la clase o que te esté haciendo alguna cosa extraña con otro campo.  Si puedes publicar el validador completo y la clase la cual validas podriamos decir mas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El patrón coincide con tu ejemplo, no es un problema con la expresión regular.

Pasá el regex como texto a [`Matches()`](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#regular-expression-validator).

```
string patron = @"^[A-Z&Ñ]{3,4}[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9A]*$";

RuleFor(x => x.data.Rfc)
    .Matches(patron);
```